# Command line parameter server while using launch files?

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have written a simple talker node that get the publishing rate (ie. value for rospy.Rate() ) using a command line parameter server. When I run the file using rosrun and give the command line parameter it works fine.

Snippet of program:

```
if rospy.has_param('~rate'):
    ra = rospy.get_param('~rate')
else:
    rospy.logwarn('no parameter given; using the default value %d' %ra)

rate = rospy.Rate(ra)
```

Command:

```
rosrun performance_test py_publisher.py _rate:=50
```

Now the program publishes at 50Hz.

But I am using a launch file to initiate a talker and a listener node at the same time. Is there any way that I can use some command line parameter so that I can vary the rate every time without having to change the program ?

```
<launch>    
  <node name='py_publisher_node' pkg='performance_tests' type='py_publisher.py' output='screen' />
  <node name='py_subscriber_node' pkg='performance_tests' type='py_subscriber.py' output='screen' />
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311226/command-line-parameter-server-while-using-launch-files?/) by [Brolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38921/brolin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have written a simple talker node that get the publishing rate [..] using a command line parameter server.

A bit of a nit-pick, but there is no such thing as a "command line parameter server".

What happens when you use the `_<identifier>:=<value>` syntax is that `rosrun` will pass those to the node and treats those as private parameters of the node. See [wiki/rosbash - rosrun](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#rosrun) for the documentation.

> But I am using a launch file to initiate a talker and a listener node at the same time. Is there any way that I can use some command line parameter so that I can vary the rate every time without having to change the program ?

Certainly.

You'd just use the `param` tag in your launch file as a child of the `node` tag. See [wiki/roslaunch/XML/node](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) for the documentation of `node` (which links to `param`).

A short example:

```
<node name=".." pkg=".." type="..">
  <param name="rate" value="50" />
</node>
```

---

Edit:

> sure, I can do that. But if I want to change the value every time I run the launch file, I should have to edit the launch file itself. Can I pass the rate parameter like

> ```
> roslaunch performance_test py_test.launch _rate:=50
> ```

Roslaunch works a little different from `rosrun`, but something like that is possible.

You'd want to take a look at the `arg` tag ([docs](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg)).

For your specific example (I've added a `default` here, which is not actually necessary, but could be a nice thing to do for simple launch files):

```
<arg name="rate" default="50" />
<node name=".." pkg=".." type="..">
  <param name="rate" value="$(arg rate)" />
</node>
```

Then invoke it as follows:

```
roslaunch performance_test py_test.launch rate:=50
```

although with the `default` being `50` already this won't result in any different behaviour of course.

Please note that in the end your question is a duplicate of quite a few others, one of which would be #q29461.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38921/brolin/) on 2018-12-20**:
sure, I can do that. But if I want to change the value every time I run the launch file, I should have to edit the launch file itself. Can I pass the rate parameter like

```
roslaunch performance_test py_test.launch _rate:=50
```

**Comment by [Brolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38921/brolin/) on 2018-12-22**:
thank you @gvdhoorn.